# Junit test looking for main resources context

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a main context where I am looking for some properties like below from **main/resources**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///{server.dir}/options.properties"/>
```

The weird part is when I try run any Junit test cases it tries to fetch the property from above location and it fails because it doesn't get server.dir location.

My point is why Junit is looking for contexts which are present in main/resources. Very silly question. But I am still struggling to figure it out. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can You show your JUnit test? I guess the used annotations will be the answer to your question.

Comment: Okay so I have figured out that there is a @Configuration class where I am using 
@PropertyResource(location="file:///{server.dir}/options.properties"). This is why it is looking for server.dir. Any idea mate how can I ignore this while running Juint ?